# htaccess deny access to file if no $_POST exist?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to deny access to a file if there is no $_POST to the file?

what i have here:

```
<Files *.php>
Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Here the File is blocked all the time.

Comment: May help by changing GET with POST : http://serverfault.com/a/270971

Answer (score 3):

You may use mod_rewrite to achieve this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.php / [F,L]
```

This will respond with a HTTP status 403 to all requests to PHP files that aren't sent as POST.

Comment: @Elevant does this work for you or do you need more explanations?